# stop php script during ajax

Tags: php, ajax, sleep

i want stop my script during my call ajax:

```
include "co.php";

include "infopagetransfert1.php";

include "senddatatransfert1.php";

?>

<script> 
     var content = $("body").html();
               $.post("infopagetransfert2.php", {
                  content: content,
               }).done(function (data) {
               });
</script>


<?php
sleep(10);
   $myfile = fopen("example_homepage2.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
   $test = fread($myfile, filesize("example_homepage2.txt"));
```

on my ajax i create the example_homepage2.txt, so i want stop the script during ajax and after do behind sleep 10

Thank guys

Comment: PHP doesn't work that way, it's parsed before sending to the clients browser, which means that by the time the sleep has completed, the AJAX script has only just been sent to your screen.
Why not get the contents of `example_homepage2.txt` returned in RESPONSE from your AJAX?

Comment: Go have a read of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 0):

You can not.
You can read PHP response data from ".done()" function and do the rest thing.

Comment: yes i can but after how i can recover the data and send to php script